# Update a model value and update DOM from button in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button for each website state which shows state of each website on server (**stopped** or **started**).

The buttons are basically being treated as switcher so i can update value of **state** variable for each element of model.

```
<tr ng-repeat="website in model">
<td>{{website.Name}}</td>
<!-- website state can have either value **stopped** or **started** -->
<td>
<i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"ng-if="website.State == 'Started'" ng-model="website" ng-click="changeStatus(website)">
</i>
<i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="website.State == 'Stopped'" ng-model="website" ng-click="changeStatus(website)">
</i>
</tr>
```

**controller :**

```
$scope.changeStatus = function (x) {
    alert(x.Name);
    //$scope[x].State == 'Stopped'


    //if ($scope.State== 'Started')
    //    $scope.State = "Stopped";
    //else
    //    $scope.State = "Started";
}
```

**Requirement :**

I need to update value if it is stopped than change it to start and vice versa.

So farth I could not find any solution. The alert Statement works fine. But I need to update model and the model should be bind to the element in html. So that when I change the button from "start" to "stop", model value should also be changed and hence button should go from start to stop on the basis of **ng-if**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ng-model for `<i>` will not work
- there opened but not closed `<td>` element in your example
- argument you pass to `changeStatus` function is an object. So it is passing by reference.

```js
angular.module('models', []).controller('websites',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.websites = [{
      Name: 'foo',
      State: 'Started'
    }, {
      Name: 'bar',
      State: 'Stoped'
    }];
  
  
    $scope.changeState = (website) => {
       if (website.State == 'Started') {
         website.State = 'Stoped';
       } else {
          website.State = 'Started';
       }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="models" ng-controller="websites">
  <div ng-repeat="website in websites">
    <h1>{{ website.Name }}</h1>
    <button ng-click="changeState(website)">
      {{ website.State }}      
    </button>
    
    <button ng-if="website.State == 'Stoped'" ng-click="changeState(website)">
      Stoped
    </button>
    
    <button ng-if="website.State == 'Started'" ng-click="changeState(website)">
      Started
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dear @tuchk4 can you please tell me why ng-model should not be place inside <li> tag?

Comment: @Umar The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive. About responsibilities and more info -  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: thank you. that is what I was making mistake in binding ng-model with list element.